# Cognos crosstab column headers are not responding to format changes

Tags: cognos, cognos-10

I the following crosstab report in Cognos 10:
[image]

I would like to do two things:
1) change the date format to MM/YY/DD, and
2) write the column headers vertically.

I go to the properties of the column headers, change the writing direction, change the date format, and the report always looks like the above image.  I don't understand why Cognos is ignoring the changes I make.  Can anyone help?

Comment: It appears that Cognos does not play well with non-IE browsers.  I tried the report using an IE extension in Chrome and the rotation works.  Still no joy on the formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Cognos does not play well with non-IE browsers.  I tried the report using an IE extension in Chrome and it works.  I still can't get the date format of the column headers to change though.